# python-social-auth require email field

Tags: django, python-social-auth

My problem is that, PSA will allow user's to disable their email address while signing up via Facebook, which causes problems site-wide. Is there any way to require that data while signing up?

I could bypass it by using a simple

```
if no email create a fake one generated like username@no-given-email.com
```

but still that's an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkot out the [Python Social Auth docs](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html?highlight=social_auth_pipeline)

to get you started...

in your settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    ...
    'users.social_stuff.create_user',
    ...
)
```

then in users/pipeline/create_user.py

```
def create_user(backend, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    email = details.get('email')[:255]

    EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+')

    if not EMAIL_RE.match(email):
        # return to a separate page and display an error
        response = HttpResponseRedirect('/some-url/') 
        messages.error(request, "An email address is required")
        return response 
    else:
        # logic to create a user
```

also you want to think whether an email is really required. If its not, just set

```
email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

and save the user and ask them politely to fill in a form later